# Turtle-graphics with a multi-background color?

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I am working with python turtle to create a code generated scene. Can anyone help with helping be dividing the screen with 2 `bgcolors`? I want everything above the horizon (0,0) to be blue and everything below the horizon to be green for grass.

```
import turtle

t1 = turtle.Turtle()
screen = t1.getscreen()
screen.setup(700,390)
screen.bgcolor('green')
```

Comment: Maybe draw 2 filled rectangles. [Filling rectangles with colors in python using turtle](//stackoverflow.com/q/37472761)

Comment: @JohnnyMopp the problem i run into then is that what ever i draw after gets filled in with that color

Answer (score 0):

How about a blue background in combination with *stamped* green grass:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 390

CURSOR_SIZE = 20

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('blue')

background = Turtle('square', visible=False)
background.shapesize(HEIGHT/2 / CURSOR_SIZE, WIDTH / CURSOR_SIZE)
background.penup()
background.sety(-HEIGHT/4)
background.color('green')
background.stamp()

# your code here

screen.mainloop()
```

Or, if you prefer a *drawn* lawn:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

WIDTH, HEIGHT = 700, 390

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.bgcolor('blue')

background = Turtle(visible=False)
background.penup()
background.setx(-WIDTH/2)
background.pendown()

background.color('green')
background.begin_fill()

for _ in range(2):
    background.forward(WIDTH)
    background.right(90)
    background.forward(HEIGHT/2)
    background.right(90)

background.end_fill()

# your code here

screen.mainloop()
```